# select query for billing statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have to design an optimized MySQL query for generating a report based on 2 tables.

I have 2 tables one for **services** and another for **payments**. I accept user specific criteria for services and based on that I have to report services and corresponding payments. These transactions from 2 different tables will be in order of service dates and corresponding payments in order of payment dates. Along with that, I also have to report any advance payments paid on account (in database terms payments not linked to any particular service)

Currently I run one query for selecting services and unlinked payments using UNION of 2 tables based on given criteria. Then I run separate query for each service related payment through a loop.

Is there any way I can get all these transactions via a single query and that too in desired order.

Here are the relevant columns of 2 tables.

**service table**

```
id  (PK)
account_no
date
service_amount
tran_type
```

**payment table**

```
id 
account_no
date
pmt_amount
service_id (FK to service table nulls acceptable)
tran_type
```

Here are the queries I am trying

**Query 1**

```
select account_no, id, date, service_amount, tran_type 
from service where <user specified criteria like date range>
UNION
select account_no, id, date, pmt_amount, tran_type
from payment where service_id is null and
<user specified criteria like date range>
order by date
```

**Query2**

This query is run on individual services on result of above query ( tran_type is **service**)

```
select account_no, id, date, pmt_amount, tran_type
from payment where service_id= <specific id>
order by date
```

**Service table Data**

```
ID  Item_Typ    Date        Amt Acct#

1   SVC         11/12/2015  10  1

2   SVC         11/20/2015  20  1

3   SVC         12/13/2015  40  1

4   SVC         4/1/2016    30  1
```

**Payment table Data**

```
ID  Svc_ID  Item_Typ    Date        Amt Acct#

1   1       PMT         11/15/2015  5   1

2   1       PMT         11/15/2015  5   1

3   2       PMT         11/25/2015  40  1

4   3       PMT         12/28/2015  35  1

5   2       PMT         12/30/2015  -15 1

7   NULL    PMT         1/1/2016    12  2    

8   NULL    PMT         3/1/2016    35  3
```

**Query 1 Resul**t

```
ID  Item_Typ    Date        Amt Acct#

1   SVC         11/12/2015  10  1

2   SVC         11/20/2015  20  1

3   SVC         12/13/2015  40  1

4   SVC         4/1/2016    30  1

7   PMT         1/1/2016    12  2

8   PMT         3/1/2016    35  3
```

**Final result after fetching payments for all query result related services**

```
tranTyp Date        Amt Acct#

SVC     11/12/2015  10  1   

PMT     11/15/2015  5   1   

PMT     11/15/2015  5   1   

SVC     11/20/2015  20  1   

PMT     11/25/2015  40  1   

PMT     12/30/2015  -15 1   

SVC     12/13/2015  40  1   

PMT     12/28/2015  35  1
```

Comment: Provide some sample data, your expected result and the SQL query you have tried out.

Comment: Share table structure with sample data and the query you tried.

Comment: Why do 4 SVC 4/1/2016 30 1 and the on account payments not appear in the result set?

Comment: @bvnbhati What is your expected result?

Comment: I have listed expected result also.  @P.Salmon there can be services with no payments, there can be payment not linked to any service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drop table if exists service;
create table service (ID int, Item_Typ varchar(3),    `Date` date,       Amt int, Acct int);
insert into service values
(1,   'SVC', '2015-11-12',  10 , 1),
(2,   'SVC', '2015-11-20',  20 , 1),
(3,   'SVC', '2015-12-13',  40 , 1),
(4,   'SVC', '2016-01-04',  30 , 1),
(5,   'SVC', '2015-10-04',  50 , 1)

drop table if exists payment;
create table payment(ID INT, Svc_ID INT, Item_Typ VARCHAR(3),    `Date` DATE,   Amt INT, Acct INT);
INSERT INTO payment values
(1,   1    ,   'PMT', '2015-11-15',  5  , 1),
(2,   1    ,   'PMT', '2015-11-15',  5  , 1),
(3,   2    ,   'PMT', '2015-11-25',  40 , 1),
(4,   3    ,   'PMT', '2015-12-28',  35 , 1),
(5,   2    ,   'PMT', '2015-12-30', -15 ,1),
(7,   NULL ,   'PMT', '2016-01-01',  12 , 2),    
(8,   NULL ,   'PMT', '2016-03-01',  35 , 3);

MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from
    ->      (
    ->      select 1 as typ,id,Item_typ,`date`, `date` as svc_date,amt,acct from service
    ->      union all
    ->      select 2,p.svc_id,p.Item_typ,p.`date`,
    ->   case when s.id is null then now()
    ->   else s.`date`
    ->   end as svc_date,
    ->   p.amt, p.acct from payment p
    ->      left join service s on p.svc_id = s.id
    ->      ) s
    ->
    ->     order by s.svc_date,s.acct,s.typ,s.id
    ->     ;
```

Comment: issue with this solution is- if I have a SVC with older date but greater charge id, t will at the bottom of the query result. I want the resukt ordering as all services and un-linked payments arranged by their date and servie specific payments go below service in date order.